# How can I grab one column from a subquery and insert that column into another table where I can query off of those ID's in another data table?

Tags: sql, subquery

Trying to explain this the best I can, I have a subquery which is looking for some document information in one table, I need to then use an INSERT INTO to ONLY take the document IDs that are returned and query them in a separate data table.

This is what Im working with right now

```
use DATABASE
Select * into #Audit
From [dbo].[workflow] A
Where object_id IN
    (
    Select DISTINCT ChangeHistory.document_id, ChangeHistory.account_number, 
          min(timestamp)
          from [dbo].[xip_workflow] A
                INNER JOIN (select  B.*
                            from [dbo].[changehistory] B
                            where B.doc_status like ('New')
                            and user_login_name like ('System')
                            and button_push like (' ')
                            and B.account_number in ('11111111')
                            and B.work_queue_system_name in ('r_queue')
                            and B.document_type in ('A1','A2','A3')
                            and timestamp > '4/11/2017') ChangeHistory
             ON ChangeHistory.[document_id] = A.[object_id]
          group by document_id, ChangeHistory.account_number)
```

Comment: Why are you returning 3 columns in your subquery when you are only comparing `object_id`?

Comment: I do understand after reading some that you can only SELECT one column, but I need some data from workflow and some data from changehistory so Im kind of just stuck.

Comment: Then you need to join `changehistory` into your main query using your `FROM` clause with a join.

Comment: This worked, I think I just needed a buddy to help me through.  Thank you so much!!!!